# Java Error compilacion

Tags: java, netbeans

Actualmente estoy creando un proyecto web con java en netbeans , al momento de darle compilar me tira el siguiente error

> ant -f C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AplicacionWeb -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AplicacionWeb run
>   init:
>   deps-module-jar:
>   C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AplicacionWeb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:856: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Usuario\Escritorio\Desarrollo_De_Aplicaciones\build.xml (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:250)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:178)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:392)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor299.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
>       at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Me tira que el error esta en estas lineas de codigo que si borro tambien me da error

```
         CLEANUP SECTION
        -->
<target depends="init" name="deps-clean" unless="no.deps">
    <ant antfile="${project.DDA}/build.xml" inheritall="false" target="clean"/>
    <ant antfile="${project.DDA-1}/build.xml" inheritall="false" target="clean"/>
</target>
```

la verdad nisiquiera se como buscar este error ,desde ya gracias , el proyecto esta recien creado , [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si limpio la  solución me tira este mismo error

Comment: Deberías de verificar la dirección que estas intentando invocar, para ver si se encuentra correctamente mapeado el archivo.

Comment: disculpa jose pero no te entendi , cuando le doy compilar me tira ese error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno a simple vista el error es el siguiente, **java.io.FileNotFoundException**, no encontró el archivo, lo que podés haces es primero ver dónde se ubica el archivo que vas a invocar, en la raiz principal de tu proyecto?, en varias carpetas internars?, como no puedo ver la estuctura de archivos te tiro ideas como volver para attras una carpeta "**../${proyect.DDA}/buid.xml"**, cuando pasan estas cosas tenés que ver desde arriba la estructura de tu proyecto, y ahí ves si vas para adelante con las barras, o para atrás ../, Ojalá sea éso, y sino a seguir buscando..

Abrazos.